# Lost power with apodizing mask

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I previously asked [a similar question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26122/lost-power-while-using-fft-with-apodizing-mask) on the signal processing community, but I think may be more easily solved from a mathematical perspective.

I start out with an image, $I$. To be able to process this (apply FFTs and such), I taper the edges to zero (making it left-right and top-bottom continuous). 
In doing so, some power is lost (quite obviously, and explicitly seen from Parceval's theorem).

This is problematic however if I want to study the power spectrum of an image. My question therefore comes down to: how do I get an unbiased prediction of the lost power per $k$-mode, given the apodizing mask $M$?

Since applying the mask comes down to a multiplication of $I$ and $M$ in real space, in Fourier space the Fourier transform of $I$ is convolved with the Fourier transform of $M$. What I'm looking for, supposedly, is a multiplicative function as a function of $k$ which gives me a properly normalized power spectrum.

**Is this possible at all, and if so: how do I make the leap from $FT(M)$ to the function I'm looking for?**

I would not be surprised if what I'm missing is very naive. I'm relatively new to this kind of signal processing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't fully understand your question (e.g., what is "k-mode"?), but if what you want to know is how much power is lost, then just calculate the power with and without the mask.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.
Sorry, I guess this may be physicist-jargon. I might as well have said the power per $k$. $k$-mode is just reminiscent of the fact that the FT is a superposition of harmonic modes, defined by their value of $k$. 

As for your suggestion: the problem is that I need the mask in order to perform the FFT in the first place, so it is not really possible to calculate the power without the mask. But it might still work if I compare it to the input power spectrum I suppose... thanks! I'll look into that.

Comment: So you don't have access to the pre-apodized data? But you do have access to the mask? If so, what about calculating the spectrum of the mask and then inverting it? If you then multiply the weighted spectrum by this inverse, then in theory you will get the unweighted spectrum. If there are any zero-valued samples, then of course it will be undefined, but if that's the case, you're out of luck anyways since that data would be irretrievably lost. This is a very naive way to implement [deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution), but it might be a place to start.